# Mage::getUrl with custom controller

Tags: module, magento-1, router

Here is my module's config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Teachers>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </Mycompany_Teachers>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <mycompany_teachers>
                <class>Mycompany_Teachers_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>mycompany_teachers_resource</resourceModel>
            </mycompany_teachers>

            <mycompany_teachers_resource>
                <class>Mycompany_Teachers_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <review_comment>
                        <table>mycompany_teachers_review_comment</table>
                    </review_comment>
                </entities>
            </mycompany_teachers_resource>

            <review>
                <rewrite>
                    <observer>Mycompany_Teachers_Model_Review_Observer</observer>
                </rewrite>
            </review>
        </models>

        <resources>
            <mycompany_teachers_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Mycompany_Teachers</module>
                </setup>
            </mycompany_teachers_setup>
        </resources>

        <helpers>
            <mycompany_teachers>
                <class>Mycompany_Teachers_Helper</class>
            </mycompany_teachers>
        </helpers>

        <template>
            <email>
                <mycompany_teachers_review_after_save module="mycompany_teachers">
                    <label>Video Comment: Email Teachers</label>
                    <file>mycompany_teachers/mycompany_teachers_review_after_save.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </mycompany_teachers_review_after_save>
            </email>
        </template>

        <events>
            <review_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <mycompany_teachers_review_save_after>
                        <class>mycompany_teachers/review_observer</class>
                        <method>reviewSaveAfter</method>
                    </mycompany_teachers_review_save_after>
                </observers>
            </review_save_after>
        </events>
    </global>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <teachers_reviews>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mycompany_Teachers</module>
                    <frontName>teachers_reviews</frontName>
                </args>
            </teachers_reviews>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

I've tried all of the following to get the controller URL:

```
Mage::getUrl('teachers_reviews');
Mage::getUrl('teachers_reviews/index');
Mage::getUrl('teachers_reviews/index/index');
```

All come back empty. I've tried changing both `<teachers_reviews>` and `<frontName>teachers_reviews</frontName>` to different things like so:

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <test>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Mycompany_Teachers</module>
                <frontName>another</frontName>
            </args>
        </test>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

And then tried:

```
Mage::getUrl('test');
Mage::getUrl('test/index');
Mage::getUrl('test/index/index');
Mage::getUrl('another');
Mage::getUrl('another/index');
Mage::getUrl('another/index/index');
```

And no matter what I try, `Mage::getUrl` comes back empty. I can go to example.com/teachers_reviews and I get the Hello World from my class:

```
<?php

class Mycompany_Teachers_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
        die('hello world!');
    }
}
```

I don't understand why I can't get `Mage::getUrl` to work.

Comment: Check ur Mage.php for function `getUrl()` whether it is commented in any case..

Comment: put log inside your indexAction() then check it is logged while trying this action.

Comment: echo Mage::getUrl? I don't know man, there is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: what happens when you do this with some Magento controllers? I seem to see that this should not validate the path but simply format it. If it does not work with standard controllers then I suggest you have something more seriously wrong with your set-up

Answer (score 2):

This ended up being a combination of me correcting previous naming issues in the config.xml and changing the router along with those corrections, and then not clearing the cache.

Comment: Consider accepting a solution if it's solved.

Answer (score 2):

For those suffering a similar problem, check and double-check your module's `config.xml` for the smallest naming errors, including case sensitivity.

Naming your router `<lowercase_whatever>` then trying to use `getUrl("LowerCase_Whatever/CoolFunction")` is not going to work.

When you use the `getUrl()` function, Magento eventually calls `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front::getRouterByRoute()`, which tries to load routers in the order of admin routers first; then standard routers; then custom-named routers. That's what `<use>standard</use>` refers to in the question's XML above.

In this case, it'll try to load a standard router with the name `test`, thanks to the `<test>` XML block above. However, if you write it as `<test>` in the XML, but then call `getUrl("Test/whatever")` (note the case difference), it'll try (and fail) to load a standard router with the name `Test` instead.

TL;DR: check your text's case.